# Why is this string unparseable?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, escaping

```
JSON.parse('["foo", "bar\\"]'); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

When I look at the above code everything seems grammatically correct. It's a JSON string that I assumed would be able to be converted back to an array that contains the string "foo", and the string "bar\" since the first backslash escapes the second backslash.

So why is there an unexpected end of input? I'm assuming it has something to do with the backslashes, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why are you doubly escaping the quotes after bar? Do you explicitly need a \ then " in your string?

Comment: I'm doing an exercise where this is a test case.

Comment: `\\"` is really `\"` which means that you are escaping the string and not closing it.

Comment: Type `'["foo", "bar\\"]'` into your browser console and see what string that literal actually creates - you'll see it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Seems like a string literal problem. For example, this passes ~ `str = JSON.stringify('["foo","bar\\"]'); JSON.parse(str);` even though `str` *appears* to contain `'["foo","bar\\"]'`

Comment: I suspect there are essentially two levels of processing going on here, the metasyntax is being escaped and then JSON.parse is in turn escaping those. In sum, four backslashes are needed here.

Comment: @MinusFour So what would \" do? That just means its invalid because a " isn't supposed to follow \?

Comment: @MJGwater, that escapes the double quotes, which means unless you add another pair of double quotes is an invalid javascript string.

Comment: @MinusFour Think I've almost got it. So you're saying in the \\", \\ becomes \ and \ is still considered an escape character so the " is escaped and the string doesn't close?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your code should be:

```
JSON.parse('["foo", "bar\\\\"]');
```

Your Json object is indeed `["foo", "bar\\"]` but if you want it to be represented in a JavaScript code you need to escape again the `\` characters, thus having four `\` characters.

Regards

Comment: Four backslashes are needed in the string literal, not eight. The result the OP is looking for *after* parsing is an array where the second item is "bar\".

Comment: Thank you nnnn, I thought that Web editor needs another level of escaping. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to double escape. With template literals and `String.raw` you could do:

```
JSON.parse(String.raw`["foo", "bar\\"]`);
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? The code shown works (though it's slightly confusing to say that you "need" to double escape and then show code that doesn't do so).